# obtain the "locked" and "tooltip" value off a PDF form using vba/excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, acrobat

I want to obtain the "tooltip" value and the "locked" value from a PDF form, the code works without the marked line:

```
ActiveCell.Value = objField.Locked  ''''' here is the problem, need the property name
```

the line is inside this function:

```
Sub getPDFFields()

    'base code: http://myengineeringworld.net/2013/10/read-and-write-pdf-forms-from-excel-vba.html

    'Declaring the necessary variables.

    Dim strPDFPath              As String
    Dim objAcroApp              As Object
    Dim objAcroAVDoc            As Object
    Dim objAcroForm             As Object
    Dim objobjFields            As Object
    Dim objField                As Object

    'Specify the path of the sample PDF form.
    'Using workbook path:
    strPDFPath = ThisWorkbook.PATH & "\" & "ALL_Forms.pdf"

    On Error Resume Next

    'Initialize Acrobat by creating the App object.
    Set objAcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    'Check if the object was created.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not create the App object!", vbCritical, "Object error"
        'Release the object and exit.
        Set objAcroApp = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create the AVDoc object.
    Set objAcroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

    'Check if the object was created.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not create the AVDoc object!", vbCritical, "Object error"
        'Release the objects and exit.
        Set objAcroAVDoc = Nothing
        Set objAcroApp = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    'Open the PDF file.
    If objAcroAVDoc.Open(strPDFPath, "") = True Then

        'Show the application.
        objAcroApp.Show

        On Error Resume Next

    'Create the Acrobat Form object.
        Set objAcroForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App")

        'Check if the object was created.
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Could not create the AFormAutobject!", vbCritical, "Object error"
            'Release the objects and exit.
            Set objAcroAVDoc = Nothing
            Set objAcroApp = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0

    'Get the fields of the form.
        Set objobjFields = objAcroForm.Fields

        'Print the number of form fields.
        'ActiveCell.Value = "Total form Fields = " & objobjFields.Count
        'ActiveCell.OFFSET(1, 0).Select


        i = 1
        For Each objField In objobjFields

        'Print the name of the fields, values and their type (if there are any).
        'will print them in table like form starting at the active cell

            ActiveCell.Value = objField.Name
            ActiveCell.OFFSET(0, 1).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = objField.Value
            ActiveCell.OFFSET(0, 1).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = objField.Type
            ActiveCell.OFFSET(0, 1).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = objField.Locked  ''''' here is the problem, need the property name
            ActiveCell.OFFSET(1, -3).Select

        Next objField

    Else

        Debug.Print "Could not open the file!"

        'Close the Acrobat application.
        objAcroApp.Exit

        'Release the objects and exit.
        Set objAcroAVDoc = Nothing
        Set objAcroApp = Nothing
        Exit Sub

    End If

    'Close the form without saving the changes.
    objAcroAVDoc.Close True

    'Close the Acrobat application.
    objAcroApp.Exit

    'Release the objects.
    Set objAcroPDDoc = Nothing
    Set objField = Nothing
    Set objobjFields = Nothing
    Set objAcroForm = Nothing
    Set objAcroAVDoc = Nothing
    Set objAcroApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm not sure how to obtain the "tooltip" of the pdf field or the "locked status?

[image: field props in Adobe PDF]